# Store Json file in AngularJS variable to use with 'ng-repeat'

Tags: java, javascript, json, rest, angularjs

The goal of this project is to display Oracle PL/SQL records in a web site.  I have used the following tutorial (http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/) to set up a connection with the database.  I was able to store and display values for a single record, but not when more records were added in.

```
Sample JSON Information
[  
 {  "firstName":"FN1",  
    "lastName":"LN1",  
    "email":null,  
    "createdBy":-1,  
    "createdDate":"2013-09-24"  
 },  
 {  "firstName":"FN2",  
    "lastName":"LN2",  
    "email":null,  
    "createdBy":-1,  
    "createdDate":"2013-09-24"  
 },  
 {  "firstName":"FN3",  
    "lastName":"LN3",  
    "email":null,  
    "createdBy":-1,  
    "createdDate":"2013-09-24"  
 },  
 {  "firstName":"FN4",  
    "lastName":"LN4",  
    "email":null,  
    "createdBy":-1,  
    "createdDate":"2013-09-24"  
 },  
 {  "firstName":"FN5",  
    "lastName":"LN5",  
    "email":null,  
    "createdBy":-1,  
    "createdDate":"2013-09-24"  
 }  
]
```

The example uses a factory, which I am convinced is holding the data from the json, but I can't get it to store more than the single record.  Ideally, I would be able to cycle through the records the way they do in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pJ5BR/124/.

I would appreciate any suggestions with this.  These are how the factory is defined currently.

```
services.js:  
services.factory('QueryFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/Query/rest/json/queries/get', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray: false
        }
    });
});

controllers.js:  
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'QueryFactory', function ($scope, QueryFactory) {

    QueryFactory.get({}, function (QueryFactory) {
        $scope.firstName = QueryFactory.firstName;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I'm still lost in what you are trying to do... Here is how I use to use ng repeat using json vars for angular: http://jsfiddle.net/uvzKn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `QueryFactory.get()` is not stored in QueryFactory, but rather stored in a returned promise object. Also, you need to use `query()` instead of `get()`, because the response is an array and not a single object.

So your controller should look like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'QueryFactory', function ($scope, QueryFactory) {
    $scope.results = QueryFactory.query();
    // $scope.results is set to a promise object, and is later updated with the AJAX response
}]);
```

You can use the data in your HTML like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
  <li ng-repeat="result in results">{{result.firstName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This did the trick.  The results are populating the way I had wanted.